# IPv6 gateway computer - How to set up routing?

Tags: iptables, ipv6, routing, ip-forward

I'm trying to use a linux VM as an IPv6 internet gateway for another VM.
I have a server installed for which I received the ipv6 prefix 2001:abcd:1234:5678::/64 (Note I edited the prefixes for privacy reasons)

device 1:
I put up interface eth0 (WAN) with address 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::1/120
I put up interface eth1 (LAN) with IP fd12:3456:7890::1234

I used the following iptables rules:

```
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::/120 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth1 -i eth0 -d 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::/120 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Option is set correctly through sysctl: net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

The device can reach the IPv6 internet fine.

device 2:
I have eth0 with IP 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::2/128 and gateway fd12:3456:7890::1234

I can reach both fd12:3456:7890::1234 and 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::1 fine, but any outgoing connections to WAN hang as shown in conntrack on device 1:

```
tcp      6 118 SYN_SENT src=2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::2 dst=2a00:1450:400e:803::200e sport=43438 dport=80 [UNREPLIED] src=2a00:1450:400e:803::200e dst=2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::2 sport=80 dport=43438 mark=0 use=1
```

and the device 2's IP 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::2 is not internet-resolvable, which is probably the cause of the hang.

What did I do wrong in my setup? How do I make the second device reach the internet through the first device?

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate /64 for each subnet.

You can't just put an address from the WAN interface of device 1 on device 2 which is on the LAN side. The router of the WAN side will not know how to reach out.

You'll need a second /64 and the router needs to be configured so that it knows that the second subnet can be reached by using device 1 as the gateway.

Depending on your network the best solution for this might be DHCPv6-PD or static routing. You'll have to ask your network admin.

Comment: Why would you need a second /64? What's the point of having the other 64bits of address space if you can't create further subnets in the bits you own?
After some testing it looks like I can advertise device 2's ip to the WAN router - /sbin/ip -6 neigh add proxy 2001:abcd:1234:5678:ffff::2 dev eth0

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: That's the way IPv6 works: one /64 per subnet. You can indeed play tricks with neighbour discovery proxies, but in that case you're probably better of turning device 1 into a bridge.

Comment: @ChristinaKorosec, by design `/64` is the *smallest* subnet that should be used in normal IPv6 networks (exceptions for point-to-point links).  If you want multiple subnets, you need to obtain a `/60` or `/56` from your ISP, and subdivide it into `/64` subnets.